# How to store value in javascript to php variable

Tags: javascript, php

script

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

how to store `position.coords.latitude` and `position.coords.longitude`

to php variable 
for example

$latitude = "position.coords.latitude";
$longitude = "position.coords.longitude";

Comment: This doesn't make much sense, because php works on the server side and your javascript code is on the client side. Your question is a bit vague too, but something that might help you is to use ajax, with it you could send the value of this variable to a php page, and then on this page in php you would take the value of this variable and assign it to a php variable

Comment: @AksJacoves is right. My advice would be the same. Don't mix client side and server side environments. Use AJAX to `POST` the variables, or use a `GET`, whichever you prefer and then you can use PHP to store the values. You can send an AJAX request to the same page as well, that's okay.